# Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<IUnityContainer>

Tags: c#

Why is this code throwing the error: "Not all Code paths return a value"?

```
private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(()=> 
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
});
```

Comment: I think you'll find that there are *no* code paths that return a value in that lambda.

Comment: Yes Here its shows no return values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an assignemt inside your lamba expression, you just want your lambda to return a new UnityContainer object:

```
private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => new UnityContainer());
```

The following lambda can be read as for each input just **return** a new UnityContainer object

```
() => new UnityContainer()
```

For further info regarding the *Lazy Initialization* please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with your code:

First, the `Lazy<T>` constructor that you are using takes a `Func<T>` as a parameter. That means the lambda you pass as the parameter needs to return a value of type `T`.

When you write a lambda expression, there are two ways to write it. For example, a lambda that returns an `int` value can be written as the shorthand version:

```
Func<int> f = () => 0;
```

Or with the full version:

```
Func<int> f = () => 
{
    return 0;
};
```

Notice how the second version uses the `return` keyword while the first doesn't. That's because when using the shorthand format of a lambda expression, the `return` is implied.

The second problem is that you are misunderstanding the purpose of the `Func` as the parameter. It's not just some code that will run on the first time `container` is referenced. The `Func` needs to actually return the value that will be used.

So in your case, you need to either convert your lambda to shorthand version:

```
new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => new UnityContainer());
```

Or include the `return` keyword in your anonymous method:

```
new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => 
{
    new UnityContainer());
});
```